# Find Node value in xml using etree

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing, lxml, elementtree

Here is `xml` ,

```
<organizations>
    <organization>
        <orgID>152</orgID>
        <orgName>This is A</orgName>
    </organization>
<organization>
        <orgID>1352</orgID>
        <orgName>This is B</orgName>
    </organization>
    <organization>
        <orgID>1522</orgID>
        <orgName>This is C</orgName>
    </organization>
    <organization>
        <orgID>1512</orgID>
        <orgName>This is D</orgName>
    </organization>
</organizations>
```

What i want is  `orgName` using `orgID`

I tried ,

```
import urllib
import lxml.etree as ET
url='url here'
xmldata = urllib.urlopen(url).read()
root = ET.fromstring(xmldata)
for target in root.xpath('.//organization/orgID[text()="152"]'):
    print target
```

But nothing prints.

What i am wrong doing here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to check for descendant's text:

```
from lxml import etree as ET


data = """<organizations>
    <organization>
        <orgID>152</orgID>
        <orgName>This is A</orgName>
    </organization>
<organization>
        <orgID>1352</orgID>
        <orgName>This is B</orgName>
    </organization>
    <organization>
        <orgID>1522</orgID>
        <orgName>This is C</orgName>
    </organization>
    <organization>
        <orgID>1512</orgID>
        <orgName>This is D</orgName>
    </organization>
</organizations>"""

tree = ET.fromstring(data)
print tree.xpath('//organization[descendant::text()="1512"]/orgName/text()')
```

prints:

```
['This is D']
```

Answer (score 1):

If I use the content  provided in the question as `xmldata`, it print something like following:

```
<Element orgID at 0x2858c18>
```

Maybe you should check that the url really give you the content.

BTw, if you want to print the text of `orgName`, change the `for` statement as follow:

```
for target in root.xpath('.//organization/orgID[text()="152"]/following-sibling::orgName/text()'):
    print target
```